# Type mismatch error while setting custom number format for particular range in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting error while setting custom number format to the particular range in worksheet.
i have tried many combination but unable to find exact solution..
my code is :

```
ws1.Range("C2: C" & p).NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* " - "??_);_(@_)" 'Number format accounting
```

how to resolve this issue ? and what precaution need to be take care while setting the custom no. format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
ws1.Range("C2: C" & p).NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* " - "??_);_(@_)"
```

try

```
ws1.Range("C2: C" & p).NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* "" - ""??_);_(@_)"
```

Note the double quotes `""` around `-`.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This resolves the issue I was encountering while setting the custom Accounting format in my excel using VBA.

Answer (score 1):

*Seeing your input, I assume that you have done this:*

A. Select the cell with the requested number format.

B. Run the following code:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Debug.Print Selection.NumberFormat
End Sub
```

See the result in the immediate window and use it from there.

**However**, the code should be something like this:

```
Public Sub PrintMeUsefulFormat()

    Dim strFormula  As String
    Dim strParenth  As String

    strParenth = """"

    strFormula = Selection.NumberFormat
    strFormula = Replace(strFormula, """", """""")

    strFormula = strParenth & strFormula & strParenth
    Debug.Print strFormula

End Sub
```